# Computing skewness and kurtosis in presto

Tags: presto

Does presto have built in function to compute skewness and kurtosis?  I know presto has built in functions to compute mean and variance.  If not, how should I compute these functions within presto?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Presto has both skewness and kurtosis.  See the docs for aggregate functions: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html